# jqGrid navigation doesn't respond

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am working in MVC3 and using jqGrid 4.4.1, I am new to jqGrid so this is basic question.

I have successfully geting data to Grid and showing first site. But when I click next page, I don't get any response.

```
var myMeasurementsGrid = $("#gridMeasurementsTableView" + randomId);

myMeasurementsGrid.jqGrid({
        url: '/DataMonitor/CreateMeasurementTableView/',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        postData: { "mrpId": dataToSend.mrpId, "chartId": dataToSend.chartId, "mrpStartTime": dataToSend.mrpFilter.FilterTimeWindow.StartTimeStamp, "mrpEndTime": dataToSend.mrpFilter.FilterTimeWindow.EndTimestamp },
        jsonReader : {
            root: "data",
            page: "Page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",  
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id" 
           },  
        colNames: ['Date', 'Value'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Timestamp', index: 'Timestamp', width: 260, 
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        return new Date(parseInt(cellvalue.substr(6, cellvalue.length - 8), 10));
                    }  
            },
            { name: 'Value', index: 'Value', width: 160, align: 'center' }  
        ],
        loadui: "disable",
        loadtext: "Loading",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        height: "100%",
        caption: "Measurements2",
        pager: $("#gridpager" + randomId),
        loadonce: true,
        sortname: 'Timestamp',
        sortorder: "asc",
        rowList: [10, 50, 100]
    });
```

Function behind is:

```
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateMeasurementTableView(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, int mrpId, string divId, string chartId, DateTime mrpStartTime, DateTime mrpEndTime)
        {
... here is my code, for getting data

return Json(new
            {
                total = listaAvailableMeasurements.Count(),
                records = listaAvailableMeasurements.Count(),
                data = listaAvailableMeasurements,
                Page = page,
                SortColumn = sidx,
                SortOrder = sord
            });
```

does anyone have an idea, why is not navigation responding?

br,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Probably you returned from the server (`CreateMeasurementTableView`) only the first page. If you use `loadonce: true` you should return **all data**. In case of usage `loadonce: true` jqGrid change the `datatype` to `"local"` after the first loading of data. So it will be no more communication with the server and the paging, sorting and filtering (searching) will be implemented by jqGrid internally.

If you have not so many rows in the grid it could be good way, but you have to return all data at one. The data should be correctly sorted. If you want to implement sorting, paging and filtering *on the server side* you have to remove `loadonce: true` option.

Comment: Yes, CreateMeasurementTableView return all my data from server (cca 10000 rows), that I could change to get as many rows as needed.


- If I set datatype to "local", I don't get data from server.

- If I set datatype to "local" and delete loadonce: true, I just get first 10 rows. And respone to navigation still doesn't happend.

Comment: @user1802491: How you solved it? What was the problem? Do you just removed `loadonce: true` or you had another problem? The goal of the stackoverflow is *sharing* of common problems and its solutions with *other*.

Comment: Sorry. The problem was that i didn't have a reference link to grid.locale-en.js. So that why, navigation didn't respond. I have also remove loadonce.